# .depth() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, api

I tried to run this code with `npm start` on terminal

```
//index.js
const api = require('./api');
console.log('Iniciando monitoramento!');
setInterval(async () => {
    //console.log(await api.time());
    console.log(await api.depth());
}, process.env.CRAWLER_INTERVAL);
```

```
//api.js
const axios = require('axios');
const queryString = require('querystring');

async function publicCall(path, data, method = 'GET', headers = {}) {
    try {
        const qs = data ? `?${queryString.stringify(data)}` : '';
        const result = await axios({
            method,
            url: `${process.env.API_URL}${path}${qs}`
        });
        return result.data;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}

async function time() {
    return publicCall('/v3/time');
}

async function depth(symbol = 'BTCBRL', limit = 5) {
    return publicCall('/v3/depth', { symbol, limit });
}
```

and my terminal display this error:

```
console.log(await api.depth());
                          ^

TypeError: api.depth is not a function
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\mikae\Desktop\bot-criptomoedas\bot\index.js:6:27)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

I just want to run my aplication to send me informations about cryptocoins market. I'm using API from Binance.

Comment: Do you have a file called `api` in the same directory as `index.js`? Did you meant to type `./api.js`?

Comment: @A1rPun yes and still didnt work.

Comment: Add `console.log(api, typeof api.depth)` right after `const api = require('./api');`.  It appears that you're either not doing the `require()` properly or that module doesn't have a `.depth` method.  If the `api` module is a third party module, then it's probably an installed module and the module that you would `require()` differently.

Comment: Are you sure it's not supposed to be `const api = require('binance');`.  What modules are you attempting to use (please post a link to it in NPM)?

Comment: @jfriend00 module that i'm using is this ```npm i dotenv-safe axios```. I've created a file called ```api```

Comment: Btw I'm following this tutorial https://www.luiztools.com.br/post/como-criar-robo-trader-da-binance-em-nodejs/ it's portuguese but you can translate it.

Comment: If `api.js` is your file, then please add that code to your question.  Did you try the `console.log()` I recommended in my earlier comment?

Comment: @jfriend00 I tried and didn't work. I edited now, sorry for that.

Comment: Dont we need an export module here to export all the methods ?

Comment: @A1rPun That's true, I didn't see it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export the function.

```
export async function depth(symbol = 'BTCBRL', limit = 5) {
    return publicCall('/v3/depth', { symbol, limit });
}
```

and then

```
import { depth } from '/.api'
```

Also update your `package.json` file to include.

`"type": "module"`

Comment: Now I caught this error `ReferenceError: require is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

In the tutorial you linked you missed the 25th line:

```
module.exports = { time, depth }
```

Paste this in your app.js file and use this as import in index.js

```
const api = require('./api.js');
```